# Sidewall cut on brand new tyre - permanent fix possible?

Tags: tire, repair

I bought a new set of tyres (Continental Grand Prix 5000). Being an idiot, I managed to cut the sidewall of the tyre with a knife while removing the packaging.

I have looked at repairing it, and came across items such as the Park Tool TB-2 Tyre Boot. However, I noticed that these fixes are only meant to be temporary, and not permanent.

Is it safe and advisable to use a tyre boot to repair a new tyre which I plan to ride 3000-4000km on, or do I need to cut my losses and just buy a new one?

Comment: How deep is the cut?  Can you upload a picture?

Comment: Buying a new one is the only and safest option. You could try to be creative and find some use for it.

Comment: High tire pressures of road tires and the ability to go faster on road bikes make a sidewall cut on such a tire fatal to it, in my mind. Even if nothing ever happened, the presence of such a flaw would invite such disquiet in my head that enjoying the ride would be impossible for me. Then, what is the point?

Comment: No, the fix is not meant to be even temporary, as per instructions:
"The TB-2 is designed for emergency use. A patched tire should be replaced as soon as possible.".

Comment: You know, I have heard of people cutting up sections of old tires to use as tire boots. This could be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a tyre boot will absolutely not be enough. Some side cuts are repairable [by stitching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0FxUqlXba8). However, it is better for MTB tyres that use smaller pressures. I do not know if it is likely to work on a road tyre.

Answer (score 0):

As your gut feelings are telling you, no.

And unfortunately it's not even good as a trainer tyre. Unless you consider good "waking up your neighbours due to a loud bang in the middle of the night"!

Please consider the trigger for the failure (and the volume control for your booming alarm) is the pressure needed in such a small tyre. If you can run at 1 bar, you would be ok, the bang will not be that loud. But you would probably ruin the rim.